# Overzealous moderators

Tags: discussion

Why was the question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64964/dtd-html4-01-strict-instead-of-xhtml-1-0 closed by just one moderator who seems not even understand the question. Such overzealous practices seem to make this site quite unusable. Why would I ask further questions if I know I am not helped? It would be a waste of time

Answer (score 0):

As per the close reason:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

You asked two questions. Firstly:

> Is it possible to use a theme for drupal7 that uses the DTD HTML4.01 strict instead of XHTML+RDFa 1.0?

You then answered that on the next line, saying

> Obviously, it is possible to make the theme itself compatible

So I can assume from the word 'obviously' you know how to do that already.

The second question was:

> how is it ensured the rest of drupal (and also the modules used) are still compliant to the other DTD?

Asking how to ensure that all markup produced by core and any number of unspecified contributed modules conforms to a new DTD is far too broad a question to be reasonably answered. As I said in the comments:

> If you want to check that the markup is compliant, you'll need to physically check each appropriate HTML render, and override theme functions where necessary. You might even need to patch core/contrib modules, but it completely depends on your use case.

If you can narrow the scope of the question, and/or add more details that will help then please do so, flag it and it will of course be considered for re-opening.

All that said, if I have misunderstood the point of the question and closed it erroneously, then please accept my apologies. Let me know what I've misunderstood and I'll re-open it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The question is essentially this:

> how is it ensured the rest of drupal (and also the modules used) are still compliant to the other DTD?

This is a broad question for which the generic answer is:

> You need to verify the output returned from the module functions, and eventually modify the output of those functions to make it compliant with HTML 4.0.

It is so generic that future readers would not find it the answer much useful. It is also so generic that is not even an answer specific for Drupal, but it could be said for WordPress, for example, when you replace *module* with the correct term to use for WordPress.

How that closing reason has been named is probably confusing, but the description of the closing reason is very specific:

> This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, **overly broad**, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

The part I highlighted is the part that applies to the question in question.

If it was not closed as "not a real question," the other alternative would be "too localized"; I think the chosen closing reason more suits the question in question.